# Morse Theory: I don't understand what the f in the problem is supposed to look like

Tags: general-topology, morse-theory

> On the torus, obtained from the unit square $Q=\left\lbrace f(x,y)\in
> > \mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x, y \leq 1 \right\rbrace$ by identifying its
>   opposite sides,consider the squared distance of each point from $(1/2;
> > 1/2): f(x, y) = (x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2$.
>
> (1) Draw level sets of f, highlighting minima, saddles, and maxima. 
>   (2) Describe the handle attachments that occurr during the evolution
>   of the sub-level sets of f.

I do understand the questions (point 1 and 2), but I can't understand the introduction. That f is a paraboloid, right? I suppose question 1 and 2 are too easy if f is just that, but how is it the torus involved? I was told to try and solve it graphically but I don't know what I am supposed to draw.

Comment: Don't think of the graph of $f(x,y)$ in 3-space (which is indeed a paraboloid). Instead, think of $f(x,y)$ as a function from the torus $Q$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For instance, the level sets $f(x,y) < 0$ are empty, and $f(x,y) = 0$ is the single point $(1/2,1/2)$. Now look at $f(x,y) = \alpha > 0$. As $\alpha$ increases, at first the level sets are circles, but once the circles start crossing the unit square you start having to make identifications and the level sets become more interesting.

Comment: A good example, which you may have seen already, can be found on pages 1-3 of this book: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/milnmors.pdf

Comment: Oh, that's make a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: Graphically, how should I draw it? I understand what you're saying, but still not how to transfer it on paper.

Comment: For the level curves, I would just draw how they look like (or even better, how the sets $f(x,y) \leq \alpha$, which I think are called sublevel curves in your assignment, look like) for various $\alpha$, in the unit square thought of as the torus.

After $\alpha=1/2$, the circles will go outside the unit square and get truncated, if that makes sense.

I find what's happening on the torus fairly difficult to visualize completely, to be honest, but it would of course be even better to try to draw what's happening on a torus embedded in 3-space after drawing the level curves.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Are you sure you have copied it all correctly? The reason that I ask is that although this function is indeed a Morse function when thought of as a function defined on the plane, if instead you restrict to $Q$ and glue sides to get a function on the torus, I can see that the result is not a Morse function on the torus.

Comment: It comes from a pdf my professor gave to exercise on.

Comment: @JaneDoé what I don't understand is how f is going to have level sets and sub level sets (the ones pictured in the pdf you posted) different to the ones of the torus itself, as it is defined on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think the sublevel sets look like, thinking of the torus as a unit square with identified opposite sides:

[image]

I believe there are four critical points (one min, one max, two saddle points).

These are different from the ones in the pdf I posted, because they are with respect to a different function.